# What is the command line equivalent for Intellij Download sources option?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

When I view a decompiled class file from maven project in Intellij it has Download Sources button at the top.

What is the command line equivalent of this button? I know there is a command `mvn dependency:sources` but it downloads sources for everything which makes Intellij/my web app lag so much that it is not practical for everyday use. How can I get source just for that one class and make Intellij show it instead of decompiled code?

Comment: The maven entry in settings has a checkbox for downloading sources automatically.

Comment: No I am not looking to automate it. I am looking for independent way of doing this manually.

Comment: That doesn’t make sense.  IntelliJ has a manual and an automatic way. You don’t like any of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `includeArtifactIds` property of maven dependency plugin to donwload only one jar:

```sh
mvn dependency:sources -DincludeArtifactIds=commons-lang3
```

You cannot download a single class at a time. When you use "Download sources" in IntelliJ, it downloads the complete sources for that jar.

There are more options for dependency:sources, see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/sources-mojo.html.

Comment: Thanks!
If for example my class is `org.springframework.stereotype.Component` what would be  mvn command given that it's file path is `.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.3.18\spring-context-5.3.18.jar!\org\springframework\stereotype\Component.class`? It also has version number which in this case seems to be 5.3.18.

Comment: It would be `spring-context`, which is the artifactId. (Group id would be `org.springfamework`. The version number will be taken from the pom.